# Path Error when trying to convert multi-page PDF to individual .png files on MAC

Tags: python, pdf, path, png, poppler

I am trying to convert a multi-page .pdf file to several individual .png files. I am using pdf2Image to do this. I have installed poppler using brew install poppler. I am unsure how to find and explicitly write the path in the shell. This is my code:

```
from pdf2image import convert_from_path

from pdf2image.exceptions import (
 PDFInfoNotInstalledError,
 PDFPageCountError,
 PDFSyntaxError
)

images = convert_from_path('Bliss.pdf')

for i, image in enumerate(images):
    fname = 'Bliss'+str(i)+'.png'
    image.save(fname, "PNG")
```

And this is the error I am getting:

```
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pdf2image/pdf2image.py", line 468, in pdfinfo_from_path
    "Unable to get page count. Is poppler installed and in PATH?"

PDFInfoNotInstalledError: Unable to get page count. Is poppler installed and in PATH?
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can see how to install poppler on the mac here http://macappstore.org/poppler/

Comment: I followed all these instructions and the issue persists @giovanni